# Loading php via ajax using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to load local pages inside of a div. Each menu link will fetch its corresponding content, that contains php, via ajax and this content is then displayed in a div. 
All of this is hosted on a local server (my pc running xampp), as I develop a theme in WordPress 4.2.2.

The jQuery code I'm using is the following. I added comments for clarity:

```
jQuery(MLinks).click( function(){ //MLinks is an array of links from the DOM
var TID=Tabs.indexOf(this);
switch(TID){ //We find which link has been clicked
    case 0:
        jQuery("#TabCnt").load("http://localhost/project/a #TabCnt"); //load #TabCnt from each page (a, b, c)
    break;
    case 1:
        jQuery("#TabCnt").load("http://localhost/project/b #TabCnt"); 
    break;
    case 2:
        jQuery("#TabCnt").load("http://localhost/project/c #TabCnt"); 
    break;
}
if((window.location.href == urlV)||(window.location.href == urlP)||(window.location.href == urlK)){
    return false;
} //If we're outside of the addresses in urlV, urlK or urlP, behave like a normal anchor
return; });
```

And the pages loaded contain this code:

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="TabCnt">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">

        <?php do_action('slideshow_deploy', '100'); ?>

        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                        comments_template();
                    endif;
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #TabCnt -->
```

Everything works as I want it, except for this line:

```
<?php do_action('slideshow_deploy', '100'); ?>
```

It comes from a slideshow plugin. This problem is not specific of this plugin, as I've tried others.

I also tried creating separate files only containing a very similar line and then loading the document through an iframe on the target html, like so:

```
<iframe src="slideshow_a.php"></iframe>
```

This throws back an error.

I don't have much expertise, but I think the php code isn't being sent to the server when I use ajax to retrieve the content.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: php doesn't get "sent to the server". it should never leave the server in the first place. if your client-side code did have raw php in it, and it was sent to the server and executed, what'd be there to stop someone from fiddling with the code in the browser and sending over `<?php exec('rm -rf /'): ?>`?

Comment: @dreamweiver No errors in the console.

Comment: @MarcB I see your point. What I mean is that somehow this code: 
`<?php do_action('slideshow_deploy', '100'); ?>`
doesn't execute the same way when I load the document separately as when I use the `load();` function to put the content inside of a div. However, all the other lines of php in the same document run properly.